# Bind click event for all children of dynamic div

Tags: jquery, dynamic, bind, children

## Problem:

I'm interested to bind the click event of **all children** of a ***dynamically generated*** div.

## Understandings:

Binding as of 1.7

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {...

example:
$('body').on('click','.myDiv', function() {...
```

Using * as selector binds to ALL ELEMENTS

```
$('.myDiv').on('click', '*', function() {...
```

## Question:

How would I bind the * to a ***dynamically generated*** div?

've replicated my project in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mw3tr16/).

**NOTE:** In Ahmad's jsfiddle (see the first answer), the child click events work WITH or WITHOUT the `*` included in the on click selector. In my jsfiddle, my example works fine (when the `*` isn) if you click the PARENT div, but clicking on CHILD elements (image and text title) does not. Now, add the * to my example, and nothing works...

Comment: have you tried `$('body').on('click','.myDiv *', function() {`

Comment: Do you need to bind `onclick` before the children are created? Is that the problem?

Comment: You can use:
var newDiv= '<div>....</div>';
$(newDiv).appendTo(body);
$(newDiv).children().each(function() { $(this).click ..... });

Comment: whether `myDiv` is created dynamically?

Comment: since you want to target all children of `myDiv`, just `$('.myDiv').click()` should be enough

Answer (score 5):

I just tried what I asked you in the comments and it worked:

```
$('body').on('click','.myDiv *', function() {
```

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rfdwrrma/3/

Comment: agreed, this works in your jsfiddle. Not sure why adding this * into my class '.seq_btn' to '.seq_btn *' has totally disabled the event now

Comment: maybe depends on jquery version or you have something else going on. or you have a typo. Idk, post your click event code to your question so we can see it. and maybe your html code might be helpful too (just the relevant part)

Comment: I've replicated my project in a jsfiddle. NOTICE: In your jsfiddle, the child click events work WITH or WITHOUT your `*` included in the on click. WITHOUT the `*`, my example works fine if you click the PARENT div, but clicking on CHILD elements (image and text title) does not. Now, add the `*` to my example, and nothing works...